# Transition of Parent fields not reflecting in the tasks and bugs created underneath it

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

According to the below article , restricting state transition is not possible for parent work items.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/apply-rules-to-workflow-states?view=azure-devops#automate-state-transitions-of-parent-work-items

Is there any way to achieve this? I am trying to update the iteration as well in a similar way. for example, moving the incomplete tasks and bugs under a user story to next iteration when the user story is moved to next sprint. Is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could move the user story and child work item to next Sprint via the button `Move to Iteration`.

**Note**: It only support move the work item to **Current Sprint**.

Steps: Open Sprint page->select the work item User Story->click `...`->click the button Move to Iteration and select current Sprint. Then the User Story and linked work items are moved to current Sprint. Check the GIF.

[image]

Comment: Thank You! That really solved the current issue . What about state transitions? for example, the user story can only have the option to close , only if all the related work items are closed. I tried creating rules for this but it didnt help. the work around proposed by Azure docs, is not that feasible as it requires lot of config changes.